# Creating Pagination With CakePHP For Custom Template Links

Tags: templates, cakephp, pagination, hyperlink, cakephp-2.3

I've following custom template for pagination links

```
<li class="prev"><a href="#">prev</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="active">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">8</a></li>
<li>...</li>
<li><a href="#">30</a></li>
<li class="next"><a href="#">next</a></li>
```

I've tried it by using following code(`cakephp 2.3 version`) but not getting the result as required.

```
<?php
     echo $this->Paginator->prev('<', array( 'class' => '', 'tag' => 'li' ), null, array('class' => 'prev', 'tag' => 'li'));  
     echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('tag' => 'li', 'separator' => '', 'currentClass' => 'active', 'currentTag' => 'a' ));  
     echo $this->Paginator->next('>', array('class' => 'next', 'tag' => 'li' ), null, array( 'class' => 'next', 'tag' => 'li'));  
?>
```

Please help me out to get it done.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a sample of my custom template for pagination links, that I made for use with bootstrap. You can modify it accordingly to your needs

```
<ul>
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->first('&lsaquo;', array('tag' => 'li', 'title' => __('First page'), 'escape' => false));
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('&laquo;', array('tag' => 'li',  'title' => __('Previous page'), 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false), null, array('tag' => 'li', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => false, 'tag' => 'li', 'currentTag' => 'span', 'currentClass' => 'active'));
    echo $this->Paginator->next('&raquo;', array('tag' => 'li', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'title' => __('Next page'), 'escape' => false), null, array('tag' => 'li', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->last('&rsaquo;', array('tag' => 'li', 'title' => __('First page'), 'escape' => false));
?>
</ul>
```

The ellipsis `...` is created automatically by `Paginator::numbers()` according to [the CakeBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-page-number-links), but you can change it to whatever you want.

I hope it works out for you